# gdata link from Firefox doesn't work any more for YouTube API?

Tags: youtube-api

At least a year ago, if I go to

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&max-results=1&q=intitle:"Relapse"+intitle:"Eminem"&orderby=viewCount

from FireFox browser, I could the list of video titles that meet the search query in this address.

But now it doesn't work.

Has it been deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

@user3123767 The YouTube Data API (v2) has been officially deprecated as of March 4, 2014. Please refer to our deprecation policy for more information. Please use the YouTube Data API (v3) for new integrations and migrate applications still using the v2 API to the v3 API as well. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_feeds)

All calls to Google APIs now  require that you send  Your Api Key, which you can obtain one from [Here](https://console.developers.google.com)

Once you got your API Key You can Make various calls

For example Search for videos using the key word **"Hollywood"** 
 Run this code and see the result in console

```
(function($){
function SearchYouTube(queryToSearch,pageToken,ApiKey,maxResults){
var 
YoutubeUrl="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/", 
pageToken=pageToken,
maxResults=maxResults,
ApiKey=ApiKey,
$.get(YoutubeUrl+"search?q="+queryToSearch,{
   part : 'snippet',
   pageToken:pageToken,
   key:ApiKey,
   maxResults:maxResults
   },
   function(data) {

//let check if request is granted with our Api Key   
   if(!data.items[0]){console.log("System Configuration Error");}
   //If request granted okay 
   var 
   videoId=data.items[0].id.videoId,
   videoImgUrl=data.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.high.url,//medium | default | high
   videoTile=data.items[0].snippet.title,
   nextPageToken=data.items[0].nextPageToken;// Useful if you want the next set of datas
   //Display data on page here if you want
   //See console Log of results that you can use
    console.log(data);//Dump data

   }//Success 
   );
}
//Usage
SearchYouTube("Hollywood","","xxx Your Api Key xxx",5);
//==================All Closed==========  
})(jQuery);
```

**See Working Sample** [Here](http://tubentertain.com/t)

Answer (score 0):

could be a few reasons.

[YouTube API v2.0 is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_feeds) not sure if it totally down now or not.

All calls to Google APIs now I think require that you send a at the very least a [public API key](http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-create-public-api-key/).  I just tested the following

> http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=skateboarding+dog&start-index=21&max-results=10&v=2&key=[api
>   key]

It returned

> This webpage is not available

I think I am going to have to say that its not working anymore you should try and use YouTube API v3 instead.